# compare hexadecimal values java

Tags: java, serial-port, xmodem

**Duplicate:** [[Compare hexadecimal and decimal values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713162/compare-hexadecimal-values-with-decimal-in-java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713162/compare-hexadecimal-values-with-decimal-in-java)

I'm implementing x-modem protocol in java, I'm reading serialport and storing in byte array of size 1024. then I have converted data to string I'm getting 133 bytes in a packet,problem is I'm not enable to compare hexadecimal value in string and also in bytearray. I've to find SOH i.e. `0x01,EOT=0x02` in data, but I'm unable to understand how to do it.

Here is part of thecode:

```
char SOH=0X01;
public void readResponse() 
{
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int len = -1;
  String data;
  try 
  {
    while ((len = this.getIn().read(buffer)) > -1) 
  {
  data = new String(buffer,0,len);
  time = System.currentTimeMillis();
  data = new String(buffer, 0, len);
  System.out.println("Data length is "+data.length());
  System.out.println(data);
  for(int i=0;i<carray.length;i++)
  {
    if(data.CharAt(i)==SOH)
    {
      System.out.println("SOH["+i+"]"+data.CharAt(i));
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two persons have fixed the formatting and you keep pasting corrected (?) code without formatting, ruining their efforts. You should try and look what the icons above the text area are made for...

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `String`/`char` when handling binary data. Use `byte[]`/`byte` instead. Fix that before you try to fix any other bugs.

`char` is a 16-bit value in Java, it's not the same as the C `char` (which is defined to be a byte). The closest thing to a C `char` in Java is the `byte` (which is signed, 'though).

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing bytes with Strings - this is a Bad Thing, as you dont know what encoding Java is using to cnvert a given byte into a textual representation.

Use a ByteBuffer and do comparisons between raw bytes as they are read.